# Vagrant shell provisioning phpPgAdmin password

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, phppgadmin

How would I get my Vagrant shell script to supply the password when creating a user while provisioning phpPgAdmin?

ie. when I supply this command `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/phppgadmin/.htpasswd vagrant` it prompts for a password for the vagrant user so I can login to phpPgAdmin.  How can I script this into my shell provisioning script that goes with my Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to force `htpasswd` to read passwords from stdin. It can be done by supplying `-i` switch.

Second, you need to pass a string into `htpasswd` stdin. This can be achieved in numerous ways. For example you can redirect stdout of `echo` into stdin of `htpasswd`.

So resulting command would look like this

```
echo "123456" | htpasswd -i -c /etc/phppgadmin/.htpasswd vagrant
```

Comment: Ah super, thanks, I just had to stick a `sudo` in front of the `htpasswd` command.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With Apache 2.2, while `-i` was introduced on 2.4.4, the below command would work:

```
htpasswd -bc /etc/phppgadmin/.htpasswd vagrant password
```